# Personalize Eclipse Web page Editor (pallette and code generated after drag/drop)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to personalize Eclipse Web page Editor by adding some new objects in the palette and I want that this new objects can be dragged and dropped to the new editor and to customise the source code automaticly generated when we darg/drop an object from the palette. 
But I didn't find the source code of Eclipse Web page Editor to personalize it.
Any one for help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.Its jar file is included in Eclipse plugin folder.
This code can be downloaded by CVS also.